# Remount folder on read-only partition as temporary writeable folder (overlays)?

Tags: linux, read-only, embedded-linux

if I type the following command

```
sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/tmp/upper,workdir=/tmp/workdir none /etc
```

Is it correct that /etc (overlay) folder will be stacked on top of /etc (read-only) folder?